# javascript and performance.now() and trimming after the decimal

Tags: javascript

Perhaps I do not understand the repercussions of doing the following.

I am using performance.now() to measure some things on my website, but a partner wants me to remove the floating after the decimal. So, I'm getting results like:

11067.64120858936

By chomping off after the 'decimal', do I adversely affect the metrics?

Comment: Simply: Yes. But who cares? Those decimals are so tiny anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.floor` to remove floating after decimal:

```
var val = 11067.64120858936;
var result = Math.floor(val);
console.log(result); // 11067 discard value after decimal
```

You can use `Math.ceil` will give you round figure by next digit i.e. 1 increment in case of float number like given example it doesn't matter whether digit after decimal is greater than 5 or not:

```
var val = 11067.64120858936;
var result = Math.ceil(val);
console.log(result); // result 11068
```

You can use `Math.round` will give you fixed digit either by 1+ or 1- depends on value after decimal:

```
var val = 11067.64120858936;
var result = Math.round(val); 
console.log(result); // result 11068 as there is 6 after decimal
```

To get specific digit after decimal you can try `toFixed()` method:

```
var val = 11067.64120858936;
var result = val.toFixed(2); // for two place digit after decimal
console.log(result); // result 11067.64
```

You can try this in your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You can also round this value:

```
Math.round(11067.64120858936)
```

Output : 11068

Well If you have other value '11067.44120858936' then result will be diffrent.

```
Math.round(11067.44120858936)
```

Output : 11067